# using functions to demarcate scope

Tags: javascript

The [Eloquent Javascript chapter on modules](http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html) offers the following example for using functions to demarcate scope:

```
var dayName = function() {
    var names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    return function(number) {
        return names[number];
    };
}();
```

It is not clear to me how the above offers any benefit (scoping and name-pollution-wise) over the simpler:

```
function dayName(number) {
    var names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    return names[number];
}
```

Comment: In your second example the array `names` will be created for every call of `dayName`  and released afterwards. The first example creates this Array only once. If you use `dayName` often and/or on high rates, this will be a performance gain.

Comment: @t.niese: If you use it often enough, the optimising compiler will jump in, spot a trivial optimisation, and you've got the same performance :-)

Comment: @Bergi yes thats most likely true especially as it is an array of primitives and the array itself is not accessable from outside.

Answer (score 4):

In first example, That **name** array would only be created once until it's object is in scope. This is useful in case if values are fetched from file or database.

Comment: I fail to parse the structure: '[thing] is created once until [condition]'